# How to access localhost (flask app) from within docker?

Tags: python, docker, localhost

On my laptop I can start simple flask app:

```
import os
import io
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
        s = """
                This is a localhost!
        """
        return (s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000, debug=True)
```

And when do `curl localhost:3000` on my laptop - I can get a good response.

But when I start a docker image and put same code and start it with same version of Python - it shows as running but when I do from within a docker `curl localhost:3000` - do not get any response (it just hangs and nothing happens).

How to enable localhost (routing) inside docker?
Thanks.

Comment: did you try to ping localhost? where does it route? Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: ```ping localhost  
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms```

Comment: Can you describe how you're building and running the application?

Comment: Did not do any binding or routing. What is the correct procedure?

Comment: The official Docker [Get Started, Part 2: Containers](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial walks through a Python example much like this.  You're most likely missing a `docker run -p` option?  Also remember that every container has its own notion of what `localhost` is and it's clearest to just avoid that hostname (and the equivalent 127.0.0.1 IPv4 address) in Docker-related questions.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to

`app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000, debug=True)`

and check if localhost is defined in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Tried this and did not help. How `/etc/hosts` should be set?

Comment: 127.0.0.1      localhost

Comment: This will actively prevent the application from working in Docker.  It must be `host='0.0.0.0'` as shown in the question.  (This is a pretty frequently-asked Docker question.)

Comment: @DavidMaze so what is the solution?

Comment: @Joe Try to create a own docker network ```docker network create mynet``` and then start your container in this net and give him a hostname like this ```docker run  -p 3000:3000 --net=mynet --ip=172.18.0.2 --hostname=myservice.foobar.com <yourcontainername>```. Then you should be able to reach your service from host with ip (you could also set /etc/host on the host to know myservice.foobar.com) and within docker with myservice.foobar.com. (If you have troubles reaching the network on host, you need to add a static route : route /P add 172.18.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.0.75.2